# How to zoom-out javafx linechart after it was zoomed in?

Tags: plot, javafx, selection, zooming

I've got this code right now.

```
public class ScalableChart extends VBox implements Initializable{
    @FXML
    private LineChart<Number, Number> chart;
    @FXML
    private Rectangle zoomRect;
    @FXML
    private StackPane pane;

    private boolean selectionGestureStarted = false;

    private ObjectProperty<javafx.geometry.Point2D> mouseAnchor = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();;
    public ScalableChart() {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(
                "hello.fxml"));
        fxmlLoader.setRoot(this);
        fxmlLoader.setController(this);

        try {
            fxmlLoader.load();
            zoomRect.setManaged(true);
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            throw new RuntimeException(exception);
        }

    }

    @FXML
    protected void reset(MouseEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Reset");
        chart.getXAxis().setAutoRanging(true);
        chart.getYAxis().setAutoRanging(true);
        final NumberAxis xAxis = (NumberAxis)chart.getXAxis();
        xAxis.setLowerBound(0);
        xAxis.invalidateRange(chart.getData().);
        xAxis.setUpperBound(Collections.max(chart.getData().));
        final NumberAxis yAxis = (NumberAxis)chart.getYAxis();
        yAxis.setLowerBound(0);
        yAxis.setUpperBound(1000);

        zoomRect.setWidth(0);
        zoomRect.setHeight(0);
    }

    @FXML
    protected void startSettingZoom(MouseEvent event) {
        setSelectionGestureStarted(true);
        mouseAnchor.set(new javafx.geometry.Point2D(event.getX(), event.getY()));
        zoomRect.setWidth(0);
        zoomRect.setHeight(0);
    }

    @FXML
    protected void changeZoomSettings(MouseEvent event) {
        if (isSelectionGestureStarted()) {
            zoomRect.setX(Math.min(event.getX(), mouseAnchor.get().getX()));
            zoomRect.setY(Math.min(event.getY(), mouseAnchor.get().getY()));
            zoomRect.setWidth(Math.abs(event.getX() - mouseAnchor.get().getX()));
            zoomRect.setHeight(Math.abs(event.getY() - mouseAnchor.get().getY()));
        }

    }

    @FXML
    protected void stopSettingZoom(MouseEvent event) {
        chart.getXAxis().setAutoRanging(false);
        chart.getYAxis().setAutoRanging(false);
        doZoom(zoomRect, chart);
        zoomRect.setWidth(0);
        zoomRect.setHeight(0);
        setSelectionGestureStarted(false);
    }


    private void doZoom(javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle zoomRect, LineChart<Number, Number> chart) {
        javafx.geometry.Point2D zoomTopLeft = new javafx.geometry.Point2D(zoomRect.getX(), zoomRect.getY());
        javafx.geometry.Point2D zoomBottomRight = new javafx.geometry.Point2D(zoomRect.getX() + zoomRect.getWidth(), zoomRect.getY() + zoomRect.getHeight());
        final NumberAxis yAxis = (NumberAxis) chart.getYAxis();
        javafx.geometry.Point2D yAxisInScene = yAxis.localToScene(0, 0);
        final NumberAxis xAxis = (NumberAxis) chart.getXAxis();
        javafx.geometry.Point2D xAxisInScene = xAxis.localToScene(0, 0);
        double xOffset = zoomTopLeft.getX() - yAxisInScene.getX() ;
        double yOffset = zoomBottomRight.getY() - xAxisInScene.getY();
        double xAxisScale = xAxis.getScale();
        double yAxisScale = yAxis.getScale();
        xAxis.setLowerBound(xAxis.getLowerBound() + xOffset / xAxisScale);
        xAxis.setUpperBound(xAxis.getLowerBound() + zoomRect.getWidth() / xAxisScale);
        yAxis.setLowerBound(yAxis.getLowerBound() + yOffset / yAxisScale);
        yAxis.setUpperBound(yAxis.getLowerBound() - zoomRect.getHeight() / yAxisScale);
        System.out.println(yAxis.getLowerBound() + " " + yAxis.getUpperBound());
        zoomRect.setWidth(0);
        zoomRect.setHeight(0);
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {

        chart.setTitle("Title");
        LineChart.Series<Number, Number> series = new LineChart.Series<Number, Number>();
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<Number, Number>(10, 10));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<Number, Number>(20, 20));
        chart.getData().add(series);
    }

    public boolean isSelectionGestureStarted() {
        return selectionGestureStarted;
    }

    public void setSelectionGestureStarted(boolean selectionGestureStarted) {
        this.selectionGestureStarted = selectionGestureStarted;
    }
}
```

Also right now I can't see selection rectangle when it's on chart. I'm using the stackpane and I tried to add rectangle before the chart and also after the chart. None of this is working.

Answer (score 0):

Make a transparent rectangle with red border:

```
zoomRect.setStyle("-fx-fill:Transparent; -fx-stroke:RED");
```

Add it to the Scene root and call `setX()` adn `seY()` to place the upper left corner in the right position.